# CASE WHEN with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query :

```
SELECT
    [Year]
   ,[Month]
   ,CASE
        WHEN Dept IN ('Fin','Sales') THEN 'Temp EU'
        WHEN (Dept  = 'HR' AND
            [Status] LIKE '%IN%') THEN 'Temp MEA'
        ELSE Dept 
    END AS Dept 
   ,COUNT(DISTINCT EmpID) AS CountEmp
FROM Employees AS E WITH (NOLOCK)
GROUP BY [Year]
   ,[Month]
   ,Dept
```

I get this following error :

> Column 'Status' is invalid in the select list because it is not
> contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: What about the error don't you understand here? You are referencing `Status` in the `SELECT`, yet it is neither in a aggregate function nor in the `GROUP BY`, thus the query fails. Also, do you really *need* the `NOLOCK`? You do understand what it does, I assume? [Bad Habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: Is not EmpID the primary key for a table named Employees? If so, there is no reason to use DISTINCT with COUNT.

Comment: Are you attempting to count and group by your "calculated" Dept or the actual value stored in column?

Comment: @Smor the Employee table is containing history of Employees so it's logical to have the same EmpID more one time.

Comment: @SMor yes I am attempting to count and group by your "calculated" Dept or the actual value stored in column

Answer (score 3):

```
 SELECT
    [Year]
    ,[Month]
   ,CASE
    WHEN Dept IN ('Fin','Sales') THEN 'Temp EU'
    WHEN (Dept  = 'HR' AND
        [Status] LIKE '%IN%') THEN 'Temp MEA'
    ELSE Dept 
 END AS Dept 
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT EmpID) AS CountEmp
FROM Employees AS E WITH (NOLOCK)
GROUP BY [Year]
   ,[Month]
  CASE
    WHEN Dept IN ('Fin','Sales') THEN 'Temp EU'
    WHEN (Dept  = 'HR' AND
        [Status] LIKE '%IN%') THEN 'Temp MEA'
    ELSE Dept 
  END
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a huge fan of common table expressions (AKA subqueries) to clarify what is going on in a complicated query. This looks much cleaner to me.

```
With Qry1 As (
    SELECT      [EmpId],
                [Year], 
                [Month],
                CASE 
                    WHEN Dept IN ('Fin','Sales') THEN 'Temp EU' 
                    WHEN (Dept = 'HR' AND [Status] LIKE '%IN%') THEN 'Temp MEA' 
                    ELSE Dept 
                END AS Dept
    FROM        Employees
)
SELECT      [Year], 
            [Month],
            Dept,
            COUNT(DISTINCT EmpID) AS CountEmp 
FROM        Qry1
GROUP BY    [Year],
            [Month],
            Dept
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
[Year]
,[Month]
,SUM(CountEmp)
FROM (
SELECT
    [Year]
   ,[Month]
   ,CASE
        WHEN Dept IN ('Fin','Sales') THEN 'Temp EU'
        WHEN (Dept  = 'HR' AND
            [Status] LIKE '%IN%') THEN 'Temp MEA'
        ELSE Dept 
    END AS Dept 
   ,COUNT(DISTINCT EmpID) AS CountEmp
FROM Employees AS E 
GROUP BY [Year]
   ,[Month]
   ,Dept
  ,[Status] ) AS Q
GROUP BY 
 [Year]
,[Month]
,[Dept]
```

Comment: This still won't work. `status` is not in an aggregate, nor in the `GROUP BY`. [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=c79bfa949d85552c53de30a3dbeea7b6)